# How to use resource text files as string arrays?

Tags: c#, resources

I upload text file to resources, the problem is that I need array of strings, but resurce displayed as string, not array.
Simple example: in there i parse file from resources to startup directory:
`File.WriteAllLines($"{Application.StartupPath}\\server.properties",Properties.Resources.server);`
And this "server.txt" is string.
I now that i can use `File.WriteAllText` instead, but I critically need array.

Comment: Are you looking for [String.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split)?

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. Are you trying to `A. read the txt file and access it in the program as string[]` or `B. write the string[] into a textfile` ?